# Marshalling nested Structs in C to C#

Tags: struct, marshalling

I'm again stuck with marshalling C structs into C#. Here is what I want to marshal to C#.

### The C function signature is as below

```
 int GetParametersDescription(unsigned int *numParams,
                             OP_PARAMETER_INFO **parameterInfo,
                             unsigned int *numVars,
                             OP_VARIABLE_INFO **variableInfo);
```

### Output Arguments

**numParams:** number of model’s parameters.
**parameterInfo:** List of parameters’ structures returned.Size of the list is numParams.
**numVars:** number of model’s variables.
**variableInfo:** List of variables’ structures returned.Size of the list is numVars.

### OP_PARAMETER_INFO struct signature in C

```
typedef struct OP_PARAMETER_INFO {
    unsigned id;             // Parameter Id
    char *path;              // Parameter's path in the model
    char *name;              // Parameter's label if any
    char *alias;             // Parameter's alias if any.
    struct OP_VARIABLE_INFO *varInfo; // Pointer on OP_VARIABLE_INFO if variable exist
    unsigned nbRows;         // Number of rows for this parameter
    unsigned nbCols;         // Number of cols for this parameter
    double *values;          // List of values, nbValue = nbRows * nbCols
    OP_SEARCH_RESULTS exist; // This is an enum
    unsigned newParamId;     // ID of the estimated parameter if does not exist
} OP_PARAMETER_INFO;
```

### OP_VARIABLE_INFO struct signature in C

```
typedef struct OP_VARIABLE_INFO {
    unsigned id;                      // Variable Id
    char *name;                       // Variable name
    unsigned int nbParams;            // Number of parameters associated with the variable
    struct OP_PARAMETER_INFO** param; // List of pointers of OP_PARAMETER_INFO structure
} OP_VARIABLE_INFO;
```

### OP_SEARCH_RESULTS is an enum and the signature look as below

```
typedef enum {
    OP_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND,
    OP_SEARCH_FOUND_EXACT,
    OP_SEARCH_FOUND_DIFFERENT,
    OP_SEARCH_FOUND_ESTIMATION
} OP_SEARCH_RESULTS;
```

I did try out making structs in C#, but none of them seem to work.
Could you pls help me defining these structs in C# and calling them in P/invoke methods and to extract the structs information.....

Comment: @user1610015
Could you pls help me with the above problem..

Comment: You might find some relevant information from [this search query](https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=marshalling+c+structs+to+c%23&oq=marshalling+c+structs+to+c%23&gs_l=hp.3...102.8027.1.8224.39.33.6.0.0.0.345.3742.18j14j0j1.33.0...0.0.0..1c.1.16.hp.1amrfQGtHno&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.dmQ&fp=9bad86cff449a01c&biw=1366&bih=630).